# MUI buttons won't center

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I probably have a question as old as time, but my buttons won't cooperate! This is my first time using MUI so maybe there's something I don't understand.

Please take a look at the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-benz-vjfpb?file=/src/components/buttons/TypeButtonsMap.js).

I want the buttons to be centered in a row, with a bit of space in between. I really thought

```
<Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between" flexDirection="row">
```

would work, but it just smashes them all on the left.

Am I missing something obvious? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change from `space-between` to `center` if you want to center align your buttons. You can play around in the interactive example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) to know more about different values of `justify-content`.

```
justifyContent="center"
```

**EDIT**: The flexbox is a container, you need to put it outside and place all of your buttons inside it, You can also use `Stack` in v5, it's essentially a `Box` with the display set the `flex`:

```
<Stack
  justifyContent="center"
  gap={2}
  flexDirection="row"
  width={1.0}
  flexWrap="wrap"
>
  {mapButtons}
</Stack>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Yes! Perfect! Okay I knew I was doing something wrong with where my button component was located. Thank you very much! I need to fix the others.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get your expectations but you can set a space between items of a flex box using `gap` property.

```
<Box display="flex" gap={1}>
```

[codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-burnell-dgqjt?file=/src/components/buttons/TypeButtonsMap.js)

Comment: my apologies! I wasn't as clear as I should have been. I should have included a picture or something.